# Are there Python tools that optimize for package size and performance?

Tags: python, bundler, packaging

Are there tools for Python that minimize the size of the imports used in a Python package, something similar to esbuild for JavaScript? Having a tool that extracts only the used methods of imported packages, uglifying them, and putting them into a single file for efficiency purposes would be very useful. I need something like that to package my Python code into a Lambda. I am having trouble finding a tool that does so beyond linting.

I tried tools like Black, flake8, and pyright, however none fulfill the purpose of minimizing the file/package size.

Comment: Such a process is often called "minifying".  Hopefully knowing the right term will help you search.

Answer (score 1):

A few tools are available to assist you in packaging your code for usage in a Lambda function and reducing the size of Python imports.
**Pipenv**, a package manager that lets you manage dependencies and virtual environments for your Python applications, is one well-liked solution. You can deploy your project without relying on external dependencies by using pipenv to "vendor" your dependencies, which means that it will copy all the required packages into a vendor directory in your project.

Another tool that can help with this is **pyinstaller**. pyinstaller is a tool that can be used to package Python code into a standalone executable. It can also be used to package a Python script as a single executable file, which can be useful for deployment in environments like Lambda where you have limited control over the environment.